# Google maps with directions on a wordpress page

Tags: google-maps, wordpress

How can I get a map that simply shows how to get from A to B with a car on my WordPress page?

I used to do this in Google maps directly, I made a map showing the road from A to B and embed it on the page. It used to be so easy. And under the map I had a link to the same map in Google Maps where you also could get written directions. But like a month ago, Google changed their maps and all my maps got messed up. The links as well. Now I am trying to fix this and make new maps.

I have tried in Google maps directly like i used to do, and this is the closest I get to what I am looking for: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start. But I find that very hard to customize, because there are very few options. I have also tried a lot of different plugins, but so far no luck.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to customize the map, I can only strongly recommend you the Google Maps API. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple?hl=de) is a good example of how to integrate the directions service into a map and display it on your web page.

Comment: Hi mrunde! Thanks for answering. 

This was very close to what I was looking for. With that link I found a slightly different map that works better for me. See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable). 

But I am sorry if this sound dumb.. How do I get this on a page on my site? :)

Comment: Hi Marteens,
I am not familiar with WordPress but I guess that it is possible to insert HTML code somehow. So you would have to add a `<div id="map"></div>` where the map should be displayed. Below it you can place the JavaScript part. Google offers a ["Get Started"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en) page for the Google Maps API. You should try this out and when it works you can change the JavaScript part with the one from the code example.
Hope this will help you!
Best,
Marius :)

Comment: I ended up finding a simpler solution for me (not knowing to much about coding). With the [WP Flexible Map](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-flexible-map/) plugin I made [this map](http://tornaia.com/testpage/testpage5/). Thanks for all the help anyway :)

Comment: Coding something with all the functionality of the directions page using the API seems like a lot of work for no reason (if it is even possible), google did all the work already, it is weird it can't be embedded.