# Google Maps JavaScript v3 on Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get [this map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable) into a page on my Wordpress site. As you can see they give you a code in JavaScript or in JavaScript+HTML.

Now, I am not very pro with coding, so I'm not quite sure how to get this code to become a map on my site. I have tried to search for an answer, but what I have found have just made me more confused. Any advice to how I could do this?

Comment: Hasn't the "Get Started" page helped you I suggested to you in a [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23978619/google-maps-with-directions-on-a-wordpress-page)?

Comment: Hi. I tried it, thanks for the suggestion. But it's designed for people familiar with JavaScrip, so I didn't understand it too well. I also tried the `<div id="map"></div>`, but without any luck.

I thought it was better to start a new post since this is a slightly different question than the last one. I mean, you helped me finding a map that could work for me, now I only need to get it onto my site ;)

Comment: You actually don't have to understand everything in detail. Sometimes it already helps to copy the code and then explore it by changing some features. Have you at least tried out the [Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en)?

Comment: Yeah, I have tried it. I copied the code in the example into a [page on my site](http://tornaia.com/turist/sport/golfbaner/poppi/), but so far I haven't managed to get anything from it. I am still trying though, so maybe I'll get there.

Comment: It seems like you haven't created a Google Maps API key. You need an individual API key to use Google Maps on your page. See [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en#api_key) for further information. You can create an API key with your Google account. Or do you already created a key? Then you might have to enable it for your web page.

Comment: I have an API key, but I'm not sure if I have enebled it for my site. So far I haven't figured out how to do that.

Comment: I have tried editing allowed referers, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Ok, then take a look at your API access settings. Open your [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) and click on "Go back" in the yellow header to go to the old version of the API console (because I don't know where you find the settings in the new version). Then click on "API Access". There you should find your API key with the IPs that are allowed to use it. To check if you have enabled the Google Maps API go to "Services" and search for "Google Maps JavaScript API v3". If it isn't enabled (status = on) then click on the status to enable it. Then your map should be displayed :)

Comment: "Google Maps JavaScript API v3" was off, now it's on. But I still can't get it to work.

Comment: 1. your key is wrong. When I look at the HTML of you page this is the key include I see `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={AIzaSyAVcVVn-AUTF5WREEHqauJ25XWj6_UFC_g}&#038;sensor=false"">`, you need to remove the "{", "}" and the extra " (at the end). 2. The key is optional, so while it is helpful to have, removing it will not cause a problem.

Comment: Ok, I took out the whole `key={AIzaSyAVcVVn-AUTF5WREEHqauJ25X‌​Wj6_UFC_g}`. Now I don't get an error from google anymore at least. But The map is still not showing. 

And is there still an exstra "? I can't see it where I write the code.

Comment: Your [HTML is invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftornaia.com%2Fturist%2Fsport%2Fgolfbaner%2Fpoppi%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  `Line 569, Column 18: Stray doctype.`. You are including a complete HTML page inside your HTML page.

Comment: Ok, thanks! This is probably because I just copied the whole code from the example under "Hello, World" on [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en) into the text editor for my page in Wordpress. Is there maybe just a part of this code that I really need? Or is there some other way to embed this on my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your given example you will have to insert this as HTML code in your page:

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="float:left;width:200px; height:200px"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>

var rendererOptions = {
  draggable: true
};
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

var australia = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.274398, 133.775136);

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: australia
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionsPanel'));

  google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {
    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
  });

  calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {

  var request = {
    origin: 'Sydney, NSW',
    destination: 'Sydney, NSW',
    waypoints:[{location: 'Bourke, NSW'}, {location: 'Broken Hill, NSW'}],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  var total = 0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
  }
  total = total / 1000.0;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for still helping me out here mrunde. I created a [testpage](http://tornaia.com/testpage/) and copied your code itno it, but the page isn't showing anything yet.

Comment: percentage sizing is problematic, you need to make sure there is a size somewhere in the hierarchy. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f749H/1/)

Comment: In any case, you aren't including the script correctly on [your testpage](http://tornaia.com/testpage/), view the source of that page.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have too much experience with coding. I just copied the code into the text editor for my testpage in Wordpress. How should I include the script?

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip for the hint with the percentage sizing. I just changed it.

Comment: I tried the new version of the code, but it's still not showing anything on [the testpage](http://tornaia.com/testpage/). I am still just copying the whole code into the text editor, is that not the right way to do it?

Comment: A step in the right direction! I found a plugin for Wordpress called [Insert Html Snippet](http://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-html-snippet/faq/). I used that to insert your code, and now finally the map is showing on [testpage2](http://tornaia.com/testpage/testpage2/). But the road description isn't there, so I tried the original code from "JavaScript+HTML" on [this site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable) and I put it on my [Testpege1](http://tornaia.com/testpage/). But this is only showing the description and no map. Strange.

Comment: This line of code is missing in your testpage2:
    <div id="directionsPanel" style="float:right;width:30%;height 100%">
    <p>Total Distance: <span id="total"></span></p>
    </div>

Comment: Great! Now that works as well! Thanks! :) Ok, [testpage2](http://tornaia.com/testpage/testpage2/) is starting to look good I think. But the zoom control, and the little yellow man (street view) on the left side of the map is behaving wierd and not showing properly. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: And also the street view isn't working. When I drag the yellow man (or the white field where the yellow man normally is) into the a street, there isn't coming any image. Should I make a new question about these problems, or is it better to just continue here?

Comment: I think now you have at least your answer for the original question. So it might be better to create a new question displaying your code that is already working mostly.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that then. Thanks again mrunde, you have been very helpful :) I will vote up your answers when I get enough reputation to do so.

Comment: I ended up finding a simpler solution for me (not knowing to much about coding). With the [WP Flexible Map](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-flexible-map/) plugin I made [this map](http://tornaia.com/testpage/testpage5/). Thanks for all the help anyway :)